# Is there a way to play full Spotify Tracks in Python and have the script act as the Playback Device?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, spotify

I am trying to make a discord bot that syncs to your Spotify. The problem is that I can't get Spotify to play full tracks in Python. So far I have found way's to play a 30s preview of the song and to control the Spotify Playback. I have not found a way for Python to act as the Output device for Spotify and play entire songs.
Thanks in Advance!

This is the Command to start tracking a user's Spotify Playback.

```
    @commands.command(name="track")
    async def track(self, ctx, tracked_user: discord.Member = None):
        while True:
            sleep(1)
            for activity in tracked_user.activities:
                if isinstance(activity, Spotify):

                    # last_id is defined above this command
                    global last_id

                    await ctx.message.guild.fetch_member(tracked_user.id)
                    if activity.track_id != last_id:
                        last_id = activity.track_id
                        print("Wee woo! New song tracked")
                        playback = [f"spotify:track:{activity.track_id}"]

                        sp = spotipy.Spotify(
                        auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth(
                        client_id="MyID",
                        client_secret="MySecret",
                        redirect_uri="https://google.com",    
                        scope="user-read-playback-state user-modify-playback-state",
                        open_browser=False))

                        sp.start_playback(uris=playback)
                        
                    else:
                        print("still the same old song")
```

The error that im getting is:
`SpotifyException: http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play:      Player command failed: No active device found, reason: NO_ACTIVE_DEVICE`

I have tried using ChatGPT but as we all know AI-Coding isn't actually that helpful yet ;)